# Get file and line of error with Ionic custom error handler

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, error-handling, ionic2, ionic3

I'm implementing my custom error handler in a Ionic app like this:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { EventsService } from './events-service';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor (private eventsService: EventsService) {}

  handleError(error) {
    const message = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();

    this.eventsService.addEvent({type: 'appError', value: message}, true); //this sends the event to the server

    throw error;
  }
```

The errors are sent to the server successfully, but I don't get too much information about them. For example, I would like to know the file and line that produced the error. Right now, it sends messages like this: `Uncaught (in promise): undefined` which aren't helpful at all.